# Check whether an observation falls within any of multiple intervals in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know whether there is a way of checking whether an observation (id with a datetime) falls into one of multiple intervals.

I have a dataset [df] just like this:

```
id   datetime
34   2020-05-13 01:00:17
34   2020-05-16 23:34:17
37   2020-05-15 12:09:17
52   2020-05-13 05:41:17
```

I would like to check whether any of these observations fall within any of the intervals in another dataframe [df_intervals]:

```
int_id   id   room   entered               left
1        34   A      2020-05-13 00:40:17   2020-05-13 05:41:17
2        34   B      2020-05-16 21:41:18   2020-05-16 23:38:10
3        54   A      2020-05-13 05:11:09   2020-05-13 07:41:20
4        87   A      2020-05-13 09:00:17   2020-05-13 17:41:03
5        34   A      2020-05-18 05:40:11   2020-05-18 06:41:17
6        12   B      2020-05-13 01:48:38   2020-05-13 01:53:09
7        37   B      2020-05-15 11:33:17   2020-05-15 14:01:17
8        89   A      2020-05-13 00:43:02   2020-05-13 05:23:10
```

The ideal result would be something like this:

```
id   datetime              int_id
34   2020-05-13 01:00:17   1
34   2020-05-16 23:34:17   2
37   2020-05-15 12:09:17   7
52   2020-05-13 05:41:17   NA
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
df[df$id %in% df_intervals$id , ]
```

this will not give you the `int_id` though.

Answer (score 0):

We can join `df` and `df_interval` by `id` and keep rows which are in between `entered` and `left`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, df_interval, by = 'id') %>%
   filter(datetime > entered & datetime < left | is.na(int_id)) %>%
   select(names(df), int_id)


#  id            datetime int_id
#1 34 2020-05-13 01:00:17      1
#2 34 2020-05-16 23:34:17      2
#3 37 2020-05-15 12:09:17      7
#4 52 2020-05-13 05:41:17     NA
```

The same can also be written in base R as :

```
subset(merge(df, df_interval, by = 'id', all.x = TRUE), 
  datetime > entered & datetime < left | is.na(int_id))[c(names(df), 'int_id')]
```

---

Or using `fuzzyjoin` package.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(df, df_interval, 
            by = c('id' = 'id', 'datetime' = 'entered', 'datetime' = 'left'), 
            match_fun = list(`==`, `>`, `<`))[1:3]
```